# Trouble compiling ArcObjects Server Object Extension project into .SOE file

Tags: arcobjects, c#, visual-studio, server-object-extension

I'm writing a Server Object Extension(SOE) in Visual Studio 2012 using C# in Windows 7. I'm using the REST Template that comes packaged with ArcObjects 10.2.

I'm able to build the program without any errors, but the .SOE file isn't created, only the .dll file. Does anyone have any ideas on how to create the .SOE file?

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer . . .

https://geonet.esri.com/thread/80929

Basically, there is a bug in the REST template.